# How to match array with object to retrieve matched elements?

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object
(   
    [CandAns] => {"1":"0","4":"0","5":"1"}
    [ExamAns] => {"1":"0","8":"0","9:"1"}
    [CandInv] => {"1":"0","2":"0","3:"1"}
)

stdClass Object
( 
    [SelectedTests] => ["1","2"]
)
```

My desire output : `["1":"0","2":"0"]`.

Is there any function like `array_intersect` to match array with objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your referring to PHP objects or Javascript objects?

In order to intersect your PHP array with your Javascript object, do this:

```
$one = '{"1":"0","2":"0","3":"1"}';
$two = [1, 2];
$result = array_intersect_key(json_decode($one, true), array_flip($two));
// [1 => '0', 2 => '0']
```

Comment: its a php object. @Tomas Buteler

Comment: its a php object. @Tomas Buteler  ..its working individually  when $totaldata->CandInv , $totaldata->ExamAns etc..how to match entire object with the array...but thanx for help .